# Paypal integration with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, state, payment

For the moment, I'm setting up PayPal  payment system on our website. I'm using `paypal.checkout.js` and `ruby-sdk` for it. And I am stuck with some problems.

I've set up webhooks for Payment Sale completed, denied, pending.

But I can not understand how to make an unsuccessfull transaction. It always return 'state' - ' completed' (even when I create unverified buyer sandbox account).

There is only one difference: when I use unverified buyer - I don't receive webhook...(but if he is verified - everything is ok). In seller sandbox account - section 'history' I see all transactions. they all 'completed'

What am I missing? How can I catch that moment when sale is 'successful' or 'unsuccessfull'. Because in sandbox mode payment sale in 'completed' right after 'execute' command. And how can i create a 'failed' payment?

I'm asking this because I need to do some logic at the server part, when payment will be successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary for you to trigger specific events manually like this, by clicking the PayPal (sandbox) website in various scenarios such as "unverified buyer".

If you want to manually trigger a specific event, you can use a simple cURL command as shown [in the online documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/#simulate-event_simulate-event):

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/simulate-event \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "url": "http://www.ebay.com/paypal_webhook",
  "event_type": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED"
}'
```

Unit/functional tests, on the other hand, normally do not use a real internet connection. So to test these, you could save the Paypal webhook payload into a fixture file, so that you can replay it at any time.